# The property can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'...?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

Hey guys i have an error and the code is bellow:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/RMxQeDVKeYPOW940bWCH/messages/')
            .snapshots(),
        builder:(ctx, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          final docs = snapshot.data.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(docs[index]['text']),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/RMxQeDVKeYPOW940bWCH/messages/')
              .snapshots()
              .listen((event) {
            event.docs.forEach((element) {
              print(element['text']);
            });
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Now the problem is in:

```
final docs = snapshot.data.docs;
```

And it says that:

```
The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 
'null'.
```

it is just having an error in docs after the snapshot data so can anybody please help me in that?

Thanks.

Comment: Read [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 2):

You need to make change is on this line

`builder: (context, snapshot)` to `builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)`

then use

`snapshot.data as snapshot.data!`.

Comment: might be helpful to elaborate a bit more on the change required.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing everything perfectly, except for the fact to add the Type for the StreamBuilder. Null safety alone won't solve your problem. Here is a piece of code that I altered a bit only in the body of Scaffold Widget.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats/RMxQeDVKeYPOW940bWCH/messages/')
            .snapshots(),
        builder:(ctx, snapshot){
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          if(snapshot.hasData) {
            final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Text(docs[index]['text']),
              ),
            );
          }
          else {
            return Text("Something Went wrong");
          }

        },
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, The property `docs` can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be
`null`.

```
var docs = snapshot?.data?.docs;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: docs?.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Text(docs?[index]['text'] ?? ''),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: (){
         if(event.docs =! null) 
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/RMxQeDVKeYPOW940bWCH/messages/')
              .snapshots()
              .listen((event) {
            event.docs.forEach((element) {
              print(element['text']);
            });
          });
```